# SSRS create custom Reporting Maps

Tags: reporting-services

I want to to use the InForm-Navigation in a Report by klicking on a custom map.
I.e. I want to create a map that looks like a toy car. If I klick on the dor, I want to navigate to an other Report.
Is it possible to build such a custom map with custom poligons?
Is there a usefull tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I don"t really know about this but I found that page, may be It could help you : [Drawing a logo or diagram using SQL spatial data](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/03/drawing-a-logo-or-diagram-using-sql-spatial-data/)

Comment: As far as I can see it only lets me draw stuff, but i need to display it in reports to click on it. And get form there to other reports.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240815.aspx
It is a maual for "Add, Change, or Delete a Map or Map Layer (Report Builder and SSRS)"